Sympy running without providing solution given initial conditions
I have 2 differential equations I am trying to solve. Running the code below takes about an hour on my computer before it outputs a very long equation if i do not include the initial conditions. I have yet to see any solutions when running the code with initial conditions after several hours. Is there something I'm doing wrong?
import sympy as sp

# solve = False

r1 = 3570
r2 = 3570
r3 = 6e6
c1 = 200e-12
c2 = 200e-12
c3 = 120e-12

t = sp.symbols("t")

V0 = sp.Function('V0')(t)
V1 = sp.Function('V1')(t)
V2 = sp.Function('V2')(t)

dV1 = sp.Derivative(V1, t)
dV2 = sp.Derivative(V2, t)

R1, R2, R3, C1, C2, C3 = sp.symbols("R1 R2 R3 C1 C2 C3")

eq1 = sp.Eq((C1 + C3)*dV1 + ((1/R1) + (1/R3))*V1 + (-C3)*dV2 + (-1/R3)*V2, (1/R1)*V0)
eq2 = sp.Eq((C3)*dV1 + (1/R3)*V1 + (-C3 - C2)*dV2 + (-1/R2)*V2, 0)

sol = sp.dsolve([eq1, eq2], [V1, V2], ics={V1.subs(t,0): 0, V2.subs(t, 0): 0})

# print(sp.latex(sol[1].subs({"R1": r1, "R2": r2, "R3": r3, "C1": c1, "C2": c2, "C3": c3})))

print(sp.latex(sol[1]))

I've tried simplifying and removing portions of problem to reduce the complexity but I am at the limit of what I can remove.
I found this question that had a comment suggesting wolfram alpha but i don't believe that wolfram can symbolically solve systems of differential equations of this form.
Wolfram Alpha Screenshot


Could you write down the differential equations that you are trying to solve in standard mathematical notation please? It looks suspiciously like an R,C electronics circuit network with voltages V. If it is then also show the network diagram, voltage measurement points and components as well.

General advice about problems of this kind. First try a simpler problem, with, let's say, just 1 equation. If you can get that to work, then try 2, then 3. Also, try setting some of the parameters to values which make it possible for you to work out the result by hand; that might mean 0, or 1, or possibly infinity (depending on the context).

What happens if you make V0 (the source voltage) a constant, rather than an arbitrary function of t?

I'm not certain that I have this exactly correct, but Mathematica returns this in about six seconds.
R1=3570;R2=3570;R3=6*10^6;
C1=200*10^-12;C2=200*10^-12;C3=120*10^-12;
InputForm[Simplify[DSolve[{
  (C1+C3)*V1'[t]+(1/R1+1/R3)*V1[t]-C3*V2'[t]-1/R3*V2[t]==1/R1*V0,
  C3*V1'[t]+1/R3*V1[t]+(-C3-C2)*V2'[t]-1/R2*V2[t]==0,
  V1[0]==0,V2[0]==0}, {V1[t], V2[t]},t]]]

InputForm= {{
  V1[t]->(200000*(-4488407412700000-20810839*Sqrt[89768148254]+
  (-4488407412700000+20810839*Sqrt[89768148254])*
   E^((10000*Sqrt[89768148254]*t)/3927)+8976814825400000*
   E^((2500*(1600119+2*Sqrt[89768148254])*t)/3927))*V0)/
   (1796430570440848887553*E^((2500*(1600119 + 2*Sqrt[89768148254])*t)/3927)), 
  V2[t]->(100000*(-5341204821113-29970235839*Sqrt[89768148254]+ 
  (-5341204821113+29970235839*Sqrt[89768148254])*
   E^((10000*Sqrt[89768148254]*t)/3927)+10682409642226*
   E^((2500*(1600119+2*Sqrt[89768148254])*t)/3927))*V0)/
   (1796430570440848887553*E^((2500*(1600119+2*Sqrt[89768148254])*t)/3927))}}

Or if approximate decimals is good enough then the result is this
{{V1[t] -> (0.9994057074186915 -
   0.5003970308071074/E^(1.4001436608549072*^6*t) -
   0.4990086766115841/E^(637186.362063351*t))*V0, 
  V2[t] -> (0.0005946463959141215 -
   0.5001486586954986/E^(1.4001436608549072*^6*t) +
   0.4995540122995845/E^(637186.362063351*t))*V0}}

Please check that very carefully before you even think of trusting that. I would be REALLY skeptical of any solution that has E^(1.4 million t) and E^(637000 t) in denominators.
The length of the input exceeds the bounds on the free version of WolframAlpha so I can't check if it can do something similar.
Note that is using V0 as an unknown constant and not as an unknown function of t. If you have a specific definition for V0[t] then I could see in a couple of days if I could make that work with this.
